# Output multiple namespace definitions with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, namespaces, xslt-1.0, prefix

I need to generate the following output :

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x='namespace1'>
<x:Root xmlns="namespace2">
<Header>
...
</Header>
</x:Root>
</x:Envelope>
```

I'm having trouble generating the default namespace for the x:Root element using xslt 1.0. I can get it to have no namespace ( but namespace2 will be specified on children of root - undesired behaviour ) or have it with a prefix :

```
<x:Root xmlns:x="namespace2">
```

but this fails schema validation. Any ideas ?

Edit : sorry for the ambiguous question and thanks for the answers. Root should be in namespace1 and Header should be in namespace2. However, the request is that namespace2 should not be declared in Header, but at Root level.

Regards,

Comment: You don't say which namespace `Root` is supposed to be in or which namespace `Header` is supposed to be in for your question to be answered unambiguously.  Note that superfluous unused namespace declarations are innocuous ... they don't damage your data, they are just ignored.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what is the problem - that XML fragment with those namespace definition is valid and can be placed in a XSLT 1.0 without problems.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to add the **xmlns="namespace2"** on x:Root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how much of this is known statically. If you know everything statically, the literal result element

```
<x:Root xmlns="namespace2">..</x:Root>
```

will generate exactly what you want. In the more general case, you need to construct an element containing the required namespace node and then copy the namespace node:

```
<xsl:param name="ns">namespace2</xsl:param>

<xsl:variable name="temp">
  <xsl:element name="dummy" namespace="{$ns}"/>
</xsl:variable>

...

<xsl:element name="Root">
  <xsl:copy-of select="xx:node-set($temp)/namespace::*"/>
</xsl:element>
```

All so much easier in XSLT 2.0 with the xsl:namespace instruction.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of using the literal inside the XSLT. That solved it for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can't map two different namespaces to the same prefix "x".  Instead, leave off the prefix for Root all together like this:

```
<Root xmlns="namespace2">
...
</Root>
```

Comment: Your statement "can't map two different namespaces to the same prefix "x"" is only true for one element.  If `Root` is in `namespace2` then `<x:Root xmlns:x="namespace2">` is perfectly acceptable:  it goes out of scope at the end of `</x:Root>` so `namespace1` is in context for `</x:Envelope>`.  Prefixes can be reused in a nested context.

Comment: `<x:Root xmlns="namespace2">` and `<Root xmlns="namespace2">` are both valid, the OP does not clearly states in which namespace `Root` should be

Comment: Downvoting. You can map two different namespaces to the same prefix (on different elements of course).